# How can I access child element of any object by using style?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm faced with a problem about to find child element. I want to access TextBlock element inside Label. But I can't find it.

Here is my MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<Label x:Name="text" Style="{DynamicResource labelstyle}">
     <TextBlock>asdasdasd</TextBlock>           
</Label>
```

Here is my style code:

```
<Style x:Key="labelstyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                    AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}, 
                                                    AncestorLevel=2},Path=Text}">                                
                        </TextBox>
                    </Border>                       
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want to bind TextBox's Text property to Label inside TextBlock's Text property. What should I do ?
I hope I made my self clear.
Thank you.

Below is a sample image:
[image]

Comment: why not use default template, but add `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/> <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />` to `labelstyle`?  default template is almost identical *and* properly uses ContentPresenter

Comment: By redefining the Label's Template you rebuild what defines the control Label in the interface. Your TextBlock is not part of the Template so it won't get displayed because it no longer exists in the tree

Comment: I'm actually want to add text and image side by side. Before, I' ve tried to use TextBox. But I can't add any image to TextBox's text. So, I used the textblock so that I can add any image or text. I can add image or text to TextBlock's inlines. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: I know it. I' m doing a similar chat application. There exist a area that I write text ( which is TextBox ). I'm typing a text and " :) " characters to add smile icon next to text. But it doesn't show. I'm finding image by using the following code: BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
            logo.BeginInit();
            logo.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Cards_32x32.png", UriKind.Absolute);
            logo.EndInit();

Comment: When I use the Textblock element I can't select any text. So I used a label and I added a textbox inside control template so that I can select texts inside chat messages

Comment: Here is the image link that I want to do.http://i.hizliresim.com/J3X7jQ.png

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a TextBlock in your label, just leave it in your template and have it reference the Label Content for the text to be displayed.

Below is an example:

```
<Label x:Name="text" Content="asdasdasd" Style="{StaticResource labelstyle}"/>
```

and for the styling/template

```
<Style x:Key="labelstyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
               <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
<Style>
```

This should provide you with the centered text in the red border you seem to be trying to achieve.

Hopefully this helps you a bit.

Comment: I used that coding. But the issue is this. I can't select text inside textblock element. It doesn't let the select any text to copy that. Accordingly, I needed to use textbox element inside label's template. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This will let you display text through a binding and the user will be able to select it, but not type in the TextBox. If you want to be able to also type in the TextBox, remove the `IsReadOnly="True"`

```
            <Label Height="30" Width="150">
                <Label.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" 
                                     MinWidth="26"
                                     Margin="2"
                                     Source="{Binding myImageSource}"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                                             IsReadOnly="True"
                                             Text="{Binding myTextValue}"
                                             Margin="5,2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Label.Template>
            </Label>
```

Comment: It helped me @Stewbob. How can I insert an image inside textbox's text. I don't want to use grid column. I'll type any text or smile icon characters " :) ". Actually this is works for me. I can select texts but When I wanted to insert image inside textbox. I' m getting an error like so " System.Windows.Documents.InlineUIContainer " this text is writing inside textbox. How can I fix that issue ? thank you..

Comment: `TextBox` is not at all the appropriate control for that.  You might try the `RichTextBox` control.

Comment: I see.I guess the only way that I want to use richtextbox.  Thanks a lot.